# Password hash con postgres

Tags: mysql, login

el día de hoy me estoy enfrentando a un nuevo reto, implementar password de seguridad con el método de encriptación PASSWORD HASH, estoy trabajando con postgress y php, pero navegando en la red encuentro información de md5, que, al día de hoy, ya no es seguro, y para password hash encontré un [vídeo muy bueno](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XfOxyQcbawc), sin embargo está implementado con MySql y la verdad recién estoy incursionando en la programación y no sé de que forma hacerlo funcional para postgres.

Si alguien sabe cómo lograrlo o conoce otra forma de implementar esta método para postgres se los agradecería mucho.

Cabe mencionar que actualmente estoy trabajando con md5

**Código html**

```
<?php
include_once "includes/valid/validUser.php";
include_once "includes/bdConection.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <meta charset="UTF-8">

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="content">
      <div class="testbox">
        <h1>Inicio de sesi&oacute;n</h1><hr/>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" href="#" >
          <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-user"></i></label>
          <input type="number" class="inputLogin" name="userNameLogin" placeholder="Código de Usuario" required />
          <label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-shield"></i></label>
          <input type="password" class="inputLogin" name="passwordLogin" value=""  placeholder="Contraseña" required/>
          <input type="submit" class= "btn btn-info  btn-responsive btninter center" id="button" name="submit" value="Ingresar"/>     
        </form> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**código validUser.php**

```
<?php
include_once "includes/bdConection.php";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $userName=trim($_POST["userNameLogin"]);
        $password=trim($_POST["passwordLogin"]);
            $password=md5($password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id_user = '$userName' AND pw = '$password';";
        $result = pg_query($conn, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
        if(pg_num_rows($result) != 1) {
          //do error stuff
          $error = "<b> Usuario o contraseña incorrectos</b>";

        }
        else 
        {

              session_start();
              $_SESSION['varname'] = $userName;
              $_SESSION['start'] = time();
              $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (60 * 60);
              echo "Welcome " . $userName;
              header("Location: ../index.php");
              exit;
        }

    }


    echo "<p> $error </p>";
?>
```

Comment: cual es el error exacto o que es lo que pasa?

Comment: Cambiar el método de encriptación que actualmente uso, md5, por password hash

Answer (score 2):

Te comento una serie de cosas, primero:

1. deberás usar password_hash() para cear la contraseña hasheada es decir que resulte una combinación de letras y números así como caracteres
2. El resultado es una cadena de 60 caracteres por lo que debes verificar tu campo varchar si acepta dicha cantidad
3. el método password_hash() es de PHP no del gestor de bases de datos, y esta dispnible desde la versión 5.5.0 del mismo

Este es un ejemplo

```
/*PASSWORD_BCRYPT generará un hash de 60 caracteres, por lo tanto también debes de verificar la longitud de tu campo VARCHAR que es el necesario para poder almacenar dicho valor*/
$valorHash = password_hash("AlfredoPaz", PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
echo $valorHash;

/*El valor obtenido de la operación anterior es:*/
$valorHash = '$2y$10$DicZpj8Jepva9ajp.4w8cu8i1XDP1q4pRppEZWSB1MvAhc40tsPIm';

/*ahora con la función password_verify checamos si el hash que esta almacenado coincide con lo que manda el usuario*/

if(password_verify('AlfredoPaz', $valorHash)) {
    return "Datos coincidentes";
} else {
    return "Datos no coincidentes";
}
```

Ya de un modo mas sintetizado pudiera ser así:

```
$valorHash = password_hash("AlfredoPaz", PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
if(password_verify('AlfredoPaz', $valorHash)) {
    echo "Datos coincidentes";
} else {
    echo "Datos no coincidentes";
}
```

> Me va a retornar datos coincidentes pero si yo agrego un espacio entre
>   Alfredo y Paz me va a retornar datos no coincidentes

Comment: $userName=trim($_POST["userNameLogin"]);
        $password=trim($_POST["passwordLogin"]);
        $passHash=password_hash($password);
        
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id_user = '$userName' AND pw = '$passHash';";
       
        if(password_verify($passHash)) {                                                       MODIFIQUÉ  esta parte de mi código pero me lanza este error  Call to undefined function password_hash(), ya tengo mi usuario en mi base de datos con mi contraseña encriptada en password hash

Comment: estas un poco confundido, esta línea de código $valorHash = password_hash("AlfredoPaz", PASSWORD_BCRYPT); es cuando das de alta a un usuario para mandar la contraseña como un hash; no debes usarla en tu comprobación de las credenciales del usuario

Comment: Mis usuarios ya estan dados de alta y efectivamente utilice algo parecido a esa linea, me refiero a hacer el login del usuario

Comment: entonces solo deberías ocupar solo el condicional de password_verify() asumiendo que ya diste de alta la contraseña con password_hash() y no veo la necesidad de hacer un select * si solo vas a hacer el login con traer el user y password en dicha consulta basta

Comment: Call to undefined function password_verify() me lanza este error

Comment: checa la versión de PHP  que usas, debes tener al menos 5.5.0 puedes hacer un archivo de php con la instrucción phpinfo(); o desde tu consola con php -v

Comment: debe ser por eso entonces, tengo la version 5.3.5

Comment: bueno puedes conservar toda esta info por si en algún momento llegas a trabajar en una versión mas reciente de PHP

Comment: Claro, así será, te lo agradezco

Answer (score 0):

El metodo de encriptacion es de PHP, no de la base de datos

Ejemplo Hash

```
echo hash('ripemd160', 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.');
```

El resultado seria

```
ec457d0a974c48d5685a7efa03d137dc8bbde7e3
```